# add and subtract in beamer overlay order

Tags: beamer, overlays

Assume I have the following beamer code.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{First Slide}

\only<1>{one}
\uncover<2>{two}
\only<3-5,7>{\alert<4>{three}}
\only<4-6,8->{four}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

After creating this frame, I decide to break it into two frames, the first one of which contains the first two lines and the second frame containing the last two lines. Indeed, I want to get the slides resulting from the following code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{First Slide}

\only<1>{one}
\uncover<2>{two}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Second Slide}

\only<1-3,5>{\alert<4>{three}}
\only<2-4,6->{four}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Notice that have subtracted 2 from the order of slides in my second frame. While this is doable for this example, in my actual file there are many such overlays that make
the manual order modification, one by one, so tedious. Is there any elegant way to subtract some constant, say 2 in the above example, from the orders in the second frame?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An overlay specification can be added to a whole frame, so it is possible to set a specific frame to start at some number *x* rather than 1 using `\begin{frame}<x->`. This is documented in section 8.4 of the `beamer` [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/beamer).

The following example produces the expected output from your first example broken up into two frames.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{First Slide}

\only<1>{one}
\uncover<2>{two}

\end{frame}
\begin{frame}<3->{Second Slide}

\only<3-5,7>{\alert<4>{three}}
\only<4-6,8->{four}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```